# jQuery label as selector direct child

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I have

```
($("div.season > .btn.active"), function(n, i){return n.id;});
```

should find in my HTML when I toggle the button state to btn & active (which works well)

```
<div class="btn-group season" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="Sommer"></label>
</div>
```

but it doesn`t. The exact same JS code worked before with a slightly different HTML. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code effectively doesn't do anything and it makes no sense. Are you trying to creating an array of IDs? If yes, you are looking for the `map` method.

Comment: Yeah--what is that first line of code supposed to do?  Is it supposed to handle a click event or what?

Comment: The js code collects all IDs of the active buttons and writes it in an aray. The full line is

Comment: @Vohuman: The js code collects all IDs of the active buttons and writes it in an aray. The full line is
`var seasons = "("+($.map($("div.season > .btn.active"), function(n, i){return n.id;})).join(" OR ")+")";`
**sorry, the code works, my calling event wasn't valid for the new element;
closed**